# Passing optional arguments when registering gym environment in rllib

Tags: python, openai-gym, ray, optional-arguments, rllib

I've been following the helpful example [here](https://github.com/DerwenAI/gym_example) to create a custom environment in gym, which I then want to train in rllib.

My environment has some optional parameters which I would like to select when training.  I think the relevant part of code is in `train.py` here:

```
    # start Ray -- add `local_mode=True` here for debugging
    ray.init(ignore_reinit_error=True)

    # register the custom environment
    select_env = "example-v0"
    register_env(select_env, lambda config: Example_v0())
```

I've tried some obvious things, like

```
    register_env(select_env, lambda config: Example_v0(optional_arg=n))
```

but nothing has seemed to work.  Is there a way to pass different arguments before training?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use env_config in the constructor and then pass the dictionary env_config = {'optional_arg': n}